# Keychron Q1 Function Keys

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard

I have a new Keychron Q1 keyboard. Like many users I've discovered that the Function keys don't work properly on my Ubuntu 20.04 workstation. The standard fix is to set `/sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`. My issue is that regarldess of whether I set the keyboard to `apple` or `windows` mode, the `hid_apple` driver isn't loaded, it appears to be using `hid_generic`.

Unless this has changed, from what I gather this keyboard should appear to linux as an apple keyboard in either modes. How do I ensure that the "correct" driver is loaded?

```
~$ sudo dmesg | grep usb

[  941.739948] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  946.345384] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[  946.495146] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=3434, idProduct=0100, bcdDevice= 1.04
[  946.495151] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  946.495155] usb 1-2: Product: Keychron Q1
[  946.495157] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Keychron
[  946.498648] input: Keychron Keychron Q1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:3434:0100.0007/input/input23
[  946.558066] hid-generic 0003:3434:0100.0007: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Keychron Keychron Q1] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[  946.559356] hid-generic 0003:3434:0100.0008: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Keychron Keychron Q1] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
[  946.561226] input: Keychron Keychron Q1 System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:3434:0100.0009/input/input24
[  946.617720] input: Keychron Keychron Q1 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:3434:0100.0009/input/input25
[  946.618016] input: Keychron Keychron Q1 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:3434:0100.0009/input/input26
[  946.618684] hid-generic 0003:3434:0100.0009: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Keychron Keychron Q1] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps,  follow these commands in your terminal

Sol 1:  add "options hid_apple fnmode=2" in /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf

options hid_apple fnmode=2
```

if this does not work you can try alternate solutions including,

```
sudoedit /etc/systemd/system/keychron.service
```

and then paste the following:

```
Description=Disables media keys for the Keychron K2 and enables function keys

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "echo 0 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
systemctl enable keychron
systemctl start keychron
```

Source : https://github.com/adam-savard/keychron-k2-function-keys-linux

Author : Adam Savard

Official Ubuntu Support :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard

Alternative solutions can be found in keychron's linux facebook group according to their user manual

Link : https://www.facebook.com/groups/Keychronlinux/

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this fix but as I mentioned the issue is that the hid_apple driver isn't being loaded, the hid_generic is so regardless of what changes I make to the fnmode they don't make any difference

Comment: You can try to install the patched driver https://github.com/free5lot/hid-apple-patched

Comment: I get the same issue using the patched version - the driver in use is `usb-generic` not `usb-apple` based on `sudo dmesg | grep usb`

Comment: I've found an alternate workaround. I installed VIA which allows me to manually remap the top row keys.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth I am sorry you had to find a workaround I will try to look for a simple fix

Comment: That's OK, the workaround is nice as I can also use VIA to turn off the RGB!