# External keyboard function keys not recognised unless I run script

Tags: keyboard, startup, configuration

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with XFCE on a Dell laptop.  When I am using an external keyboard   the function keys are not correctly detected- for example in Intellij IDE.

I have a work-around which I got from amazon of all places - someone else who reviewed the keyboard added the snippet and it works fine:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

However this has to be run in a terminal every session.

So I would like to run this (or something like it) automatically - probably every time a user starts a session, But I do not mind if the ode is run multiple times (I think it is idempotent).  What is the easiest and safest way to achieve this?  I can use command line and have furtled in various bits of the sensitive configuration stuff, but I do not really know what I am doing so cannot easily backout/repair/troubleshoot stuff when I mess up.

Most solutions that I have found involve plumbing something into systemd but I am not sure it should need to be that complicated....

All help gratefully received.  (I am happy to dump system information and copy it here - but thought it may be a noisy distraction)

I did try the solution suggested in [Keychron Q1 Function Keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398450/keychron-q1-function-keys)but itmade no difference.

Phill

My apologies for posting the wrong version originally.

Comment: You say you are running Ubuntu 22 so you must be using Ubuntu Core 22. That is the only version to use a single digit number. If it is not that version please edit the question and put in the actual version.

Comment: Edited, sorry....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this has to be in effect as you start your computer, the easiest way will be to execute the command @reboot in a root cron job:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

to open the root's crontab file for editing.

Add the line

```
@reboot echo 0 | tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

Save and exit. The command now will be executed at every boot. `sudo` is not needed because these cron jobs run as root.

b.t.w., there is no need to use `tee`;  `echo 0 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` should work equally well.

Comment: Thanks Vanadium.  That works a treat- at (least for the user I used to set it up).  I was initially thrown by the suggested file being in the temp directory so I read up a little about crontab edit.  I like the extra feeling of security from knowing that crontab will check my input.